# Adding more cpp items in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and I am having a problem saving more than one cpp item within a solution/project.

When I first create a project I can create a new item, write the code and Debug the program normally. But, when I add a new item into that same project and write the code and try to debug it I get this error:

Unable to start program 'Directory' The system cannot find the file specified.

I checked the directory, the file is there and I can open it but I cannot debug it. I would like someone with experience to help me with this problem. Thank you, I am waiting for answers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cjhy.png

Comment: That's a common case if your user doesn't have rights to access all files in that directory. Try reproducing this issue from administator account.

Comment: Try not having spaces in the filename.

Comment: I am not using space in the filename. And I have administrator access, It says right on the top, Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express (Administrator)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is about file Directory.exe. If you don't have that file then there were build errors.  See the VC++ Output window for build errors. You have to fix them and then try building again. No exe file is produced if there are any build errors.

Comment: I create a new cpp item with the exact same code as the first one but it will still give me the error.

Comment: What does it say in the Output window?